# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^n \int_0^n |x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n)|dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, asymptotics, gamma-function

> What is
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^n 
> \int_0^n \left| x(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-n) \right| \, dx?
> $$

Context: I was trying to find an asymptotic expression for the total area of the regions enclosed by $y = x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\cdots(x-n)$ and the $x$-axis. Through trial and error, it seems that
$$
\int_0^n \left| x(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-n) \right|\, dx 
\approx 2\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
$$
for large $n$, but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: That asymptotic expression in $n$ sure brings [Stirling's approximation of factorial](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stirling%27s_approximation) to mind.

Comment: nice problem. this can't be calculated precisely by splitting this integral to incremental regions and some clever subs ?

Comment: [Follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4659836/398708) about the turning point in $x\in(0,1)$ on $y=|x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n)|$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We claim that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{n} |x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)| \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{2(n!)}{\log^2 n}(1 + o(1)) \tag{*}
\end{align*}

as $n\to\infty$. In particular, OP's limit diverges to $\infty$.

---

**Step 1.** Note that, if $k \in \{2, 3, \ldots, n-1\}$ and $x \in [k-1, k]$, then

$$ |x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)| \leq k!(n+1-k)! = \frac{(n+1)!}{\binom{n+1}{k}}. $$

Now by using the unimodality of the binomial coefficient,

\begin{align*}
&\int_{1}^{n-1} |x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)| \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\qquad
\leq (n+1)! \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\binom{n+1}{k}}
\leq (n+1)! \left[ \frac{2}{\binom{n+1}{2}} + \frac{n-4}{\binom{n+1}{3}} \right],
\end{align*}

which is $\mathcal{O}(n!/n)$.

**Step 2.** For $x \in [0, 1]$, Stirling's approximation shows that

\begin{align*}
|x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)|
&= \frac{x \Gamma(n+1-x)}{\Gamma(1-x)}
= \frac{x n^{-x}}{\Gamma(1-x)} n! (1 + \mathcal{O}(n^{-1})),
\end{align*}

where the implicit bound for the error term $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1})$ is uniform in $x$. So,

\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{1} |x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)| \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= n! (1 + \mathcal{O}(n^{-1})) \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x n^{-x}}{\Gamma(1-x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{n!}{\log^2 n} (1 + \mathcal{O}(n^{-1})) \int_{0}^{\log n} \frac{x e^{-x}}{\Gamma(1-x/\log n)} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

However, by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$ \int_{0}^{\log n} \frac{x e^{-x}}{\Gamma(1-x/\log n)} \, \mathrm{d}x \to \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x = 1 $$

as $n \to \infty$. Finally, combining this with the previous step, we conclude $\text{(*)}$.

Comment: (+1) So the limit in the OP diverges, right?

Comment: @Dan, Indeed. I revised my answer to clarify that point. :)

Comment: In the second inequality, I think there's a missing $(n+1)!$.

Comment: @Dan, D'oh! You are right. I fixed it.