# Asymptotic expressions for the coordinates of the turning point in $x\in(0,1)$ on $y=|x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n)|$ as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics, gamma-function, stationary-point

> What are asymptotic expressions for the coordinates of the turning point in $x\in(0,1)$ on $y=|x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n)|$ as $n\to\infty$ ?

Here is the graph for $n=10$.

[image]

The turning point in $x\in(0,1)$ on $y=\color{red}{\frac{\log{n}}{n!}}|x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n)|$ has the following approximate coordinates:

$n=10: (0.2854, 0.2644)$
$n=20: (0.2450, 0.2877)$
$n=40: (0.2131, 0.3031)$
$n=80: (0.1879, 0.3137)$
$n=160: (0.1675, 0.3215)$

I'm guessing the asymptotic expressions will be something like $\left(\frac{1}{\log{n}},\frac{n!}{k\log{n}}\right)$ for some constant $k$.

This is a follow-up question to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4659162/398708) about the total area of the regions enclosed by $y=|x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-n)|$ and the $x$-axis.

Comment: A tiny remark : there is no need to use an absolute value.

Comment: @JeanMarie Without absolute value, the turning point could be above or below the $x$-axis, depending on the parity of $n$.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see this side (intended pun) of the question  ...

Comment: $$f(x)=|x(x-1)\dots(x-n)|=\frac{x\Gamma(1-x)(1-x)\dots(n-x)}{\Gamma(1-x)}\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x)}=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}\pi\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(n+1-x)$$
$$f'(x_0)=0\,\Rightarrow\,\pi\cot\pi x_0+\psi(1+x_0)=\psi(n+1-x_0)$$
For $n\to\infty\,\,x_0\to0$. Given that $\psi(n)\sim\ln n\,(\,\gg1)$ and $\psi(1)=-\gamma$
$$\frac1{x_0}-\gamma\approx\ln n\,\Rightarrow\,x_0\approx\frac1{\gamma+\ln n}$$
For $n=160\,\,x_0\approx0.1769...$

Comment: An asymptotic expansion is as follows: $$
x_0  \sim \frac{1}{{\log (n) + \gamma }} - \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6}\frac{1}{{(\log (n) + \gamma )^3 }} + \frac{{2\pi ^4 }}{{45}}\frac{1}{{(\log (n) + \gamma )^5 }} -  \ldots 
$$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

As @Svyatoslav already wrote in comments, you need to find the zero of function
$$g(x)=\pi  \cos (\pi  x)-\sin (\pi  x) \big(\psi ^{(0)}(n-x+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(x+1)\big)$$ for large values of $n$ that is to say for small $x$ as you noticed.

Expanded as a series around $x=0$
$$g(x)=\pi -\pi   H_n\,x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ gives, as a first estimate
$$\color{blue}{x_0=\frac{1}{H_n}}$$

It is easy to show that $g(x_0)<0$ and $g''(x_0) >0$. So, using Newton method, by Darboux theorem, $x_1$ is an overestimate of the solution but not too bad
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 10 & 0.284409 &  0.285421 \\
 20 & 0.244703 &  0.244995 \\
 30 & 0.225306 &  0.225460 \\
 40 & 0.213043 &  0.213144 \\
 50 & 0.204299 &  0.204372 \\
 60 & 0.197609 &  0.197666 \\
 70 & 0.192250 &  0.192296 \\
 80 & 0.187813 &  0.187853 \\
  90 & 0.184051 &  0.184085 \\
 100 & 0.180800 &  0.180829 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, the second iterate
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x_2 & \text{solution} \\
  5 & 0.3365508733 &  0.3365534733 \\
 10 & 0.2854211662 &  0.2854213370 \\
 15 & 0.2606074001 &  0.2606074400 \\
 20 & 0.2449953893 &  0.2449954044 \\
 25 & 0.2339092745 &  0.2339092819 \\
 30 & 0.2254596051 &  0.2254596093 \\
 35 & 0.2187123217 &  0.2187123217 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Since you need the first derivative
$$g'(x)=\pi  \cos (\pi  x) (\psi ^{(0)}(x+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(n-x+1))+$$ $$\sin (\pi  x) \left(\psi ^{(1)}(n-x+1)+\psi ^{(1)}(x+1)-\pi
   ^2\right)$$